Getting "Content unavailable" issue with File Provider in iOS 17.4 but working well with iOS 17.2
I have verified NSExtensionPrincipalClass, appGroup. We are using authentication with File Provider UI but when I tried to debug the extension, AppDelegate is getting called instead if initialising the File Provider extension class with iOS 17.4 but it's working well with 17.2

